# perl: how loop over a hash

Tags: perl, hash

I've found a lot of different answers to this question, and none seem to work (?!)

Here's what I have:

```
my %FORM = ["a"=>"0AD", "b"=>"johnny manziel", "c"=>"lincoln"];
#my @k = keys (%FORM);
#for my $iter (@k) { print "$iter\n"; }
#for my $key (keys %FORM) {
#   print "\t";
#   print $FORM{$key};
#   print "\n";
#}

while ( ($key, $value) = each %FORM )
{
  print "key: $key, value: $FORM{$key}\n";
}
```

typical output:

```
./testprinthash.pl
key: ARRAY(0x13a2998), value:
```

I always get an array instead of a key value

Comment: `use warnings;` is always helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use parenthesis `( )` when assigning to a hash, not square brackets `[ ]`.

```
my %FORM = ("a"=>"0AD", "b"=>"johnny manziel", "c"=>"lincoln");
```

The `[ ]` create an ARRAY **reference**, which is not what you want.

Check

- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Comment: His original assignment was equivalent to `my %FORM = ("ARRAY(0x13a2998)" => undef);` (although the number in the parentheses will vary).